# When is Generic.xaml applied?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, custom-controls

My `Generic.xaml` theme is correctly applied, however, I'm interested in the details when the styles within it are applied. When a new element is created and added to the visual tree, for sure somewhere in between the style is applied, but is this style ever reapplied?

I've got a scenario where an element is unloaded (the window within which it is contained is closed), and later added again to another visual tree (the window is recreated). The problem is the style does not seem to be reapplied, which I was hoping to happen so the bindings within the template and such are reevaluated.

So the concrete question:

- When are styles within `Generic.xaml` applied, and are they ever reapplied/can they be reapplied?